# Unable to add the DKIM signature while using uakari wrapper API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Uakari Wrapper API to integrate my Emailing with mail Chimp STS API. I am adding the DKIM since mail Chimp doesnt add the DKIM signature.

I referred the following git hub repos
https://github.com/jhawthorn/dkim
https://github.com/amro/uakari
But unable to add the signature.

Suggest me the work around for this, that would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of the dkim gem.

I have no experience with mailchimp, but from the looks of this STS API call http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/sts/1.0/sendemail.func.php, there is no way to pass in arbitrary email headers. To sign DKIM yourself using amazon SES requires using the SendRawEmail method. mailchimp doesn't seem to offer an equivalent method.

For workarounds, I suggest seeing if you can get mailchimp to do the dkim signing for you http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-can-i-authenticate-my-campaigns. Alternatively, you could use amazon SES directly.

Best of luck

Comment: hey thanks for the replying back, I spoke to mailchimp developers, I am building a email analytical tool, thought I could I could use this, alternatively I got postageapp.com will figure out some thing for this